# jQuery(window).height() is increasing when i minimize the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calculating the window height on resize. On minimization of the browser (Firefox 39.x) window, the window height increases from 55 to 83.The problem is with the firefox 39.x version which has weird behavior for jQuery(window).height() and works find in chrome. My code is below.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <body>
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <div id="divTest"></div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            jQuery("#divTest").html("height:"+jQuery(this).height()+"width:"+jQuery(this).width());
        });

        jQuery("#divTest").html("height:"+jQuery(window).height()+"width:"+jQuery(window).width());
    </script>
</html>
```

So i am trying to use window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth instead of jQuery window width/height. Let me know any thing we can use in better for window width and height that work across browsers and how jquery window height/width different from window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth.

Comment: nothing changes for me

Comment: please provide demo that replicates this. Makes no sense. Code shown performs exactly as would be expected. Highly unlikely window is only  55px high? Sounds like code shown is different than code that gives that value

Answer (score 1):

just try this code :

```js
$(window).on('resize load',function(){
       $("#divTest").html("Height: " + $(this).height() + "px / Width: " + $(this).width() + "px");
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<h2>Test</h2>
<div id="divTest"></div>
```

Comment: Please may you add more context to your answer. E.g. Why does it work? What does it solve? etc.